# Google authorship information, for a whole website?

Tags: google-search

To make Google Authorship Information work, you should follow some steps one of which is to login to your Google profile, and add the links of the articles you've contributed to.

This is a good step, as much as you are only a contributor of few articles, or you've contributed to articles across many websites, and many domains.

But if you are the owner of a website, and you have large number of articles (say 100 articles and more for example), then it gets tediuse and uncomfortable task to add each article's URL to your Google Profile.

Does Google has a feature to tell it that you own a website, so that it knows that the author of each article on that website is you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently this feature only works on a per article basis. But I would think whatever software you are using would offer a plug in or add-on to make this process easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this programatically with jQuery I would imagine. [there's a decent article here about achieving this in wordpress](http://sodeve.net/2011/11/how-to-show-authorship-in-google-search-result-for-wordpress-blog/)

Answer (score 1):

Once Google approves your Authorship for a particular blog or website, all posts and pages on it will automatically receive the Google Authorship Markup. You do not have to add each article's URL to the Google profile.

Comment: Can you prove that? Do you have a formal document reference for that @Vinay?